# saving contents with file put contents

Tags: php, image, save

i'm trying to get google steetview tiles and save them. But file_get_contents doesn't like my url:

here's my code:

```
$img = "http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid="+$panorama_id+"&zoom=3&x="+$i+"&y='"+$x+"'";
$url = ""+$panorama_id+"Xval"+$i.+"Yval"+$x+".jpg";


file_put_contents($url, file_get_contents($img));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `+` for concatenation.  That's not PHP.  You need the dot `.` operator instead:

```
$img = "http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid=" . $panorama_id . "&zoom=3&x=" . $i . "&y='" . $x . "'"; 
$url = $panorama_id . "Xval" . $i . "Yval" . $x . ".jpg";
```

See [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in the PHP manual.

Alternatively, with double quoted strings, variables within the string will be parsed.  [See the manual page for the string type.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

```
$img = "http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid=$panorama_id&zoom=3&x=$i&y='$x'"; 
$url = "${panorama_id}Xval${i}Yval${x}.jpg";
```